# UnityFramework does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile <my profile name> has been manually specified

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, azure-pipelines, auto-build

I'm using azure for building a unity project for IOS. I'm using Task XCode Build but It appears with this error

```
error: UnityFramework does not support provisioning profiles. UnityFramework does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile <<my profile name>> has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'UnityFramework' from project 'Unity-iPhone')
```

I tried several ways but this error still appeared. Have anyone encountered this error? Please give me some tips for solving it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that UnityFramework is automatically signed, and UnityFramework does not require any signature, so this error occurs.

CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY, PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER These two parameters need to be configured separately for Unity-iPhone and UnityFramework.

You may use automatic signing for a try.
[automatic signing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1g6Az.png)